# Thymeleaf: como inserir um include dentro de outro include?

Tags: thymeleaf

Estou incluindo um footer da seguinte maneira na minha home:

```
<div th:replace="footer :: footer"></div>
```

E dentro do footer preciso incluir alguns overlays:

```
    <div th:include="overlay-terminos-condiciones"></div>
    <div th:include="overlay-protecion-datos"></div>
```

Porém eu tento chamar da mesma maneira que o footer e não funciona como o esperado, qual a forma correta de chamar um include dentro do outro? Eles estão todos na mesma pasta, tanto o footer.html quanto os .html dos overlays.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia incluir dentro do fragmento footer outros dois fragmentos e substituir este com o `th:replace` conforme feito com o próprio `footer`. Com o `th:include` o fragmento será colocado dentro da `<div>` e com o `replace` a `<div>` será subistituída completamente pelo conteúdo do fragmento. Espero ter ajudado.